Unable to restrict UCP access to tmfifo_net0 using UCX_NET_DEVICES when using UCX in bluefield-2 DOCA
When I run the DOCA allreuce application example:
https://docs.nvidia.com/doca/sdk/nvidia+doca+allreduce+application+guide/index.html
I find that even though I have set UCX_NET_DEVICES=mlx5_2:1 about the daemon on the bluefield. However, it still occurs:
[1705390365.690653] [localhost:3913797:0]       wireup_cm.c:1250 UCX  ERROR listener 0xaaaad7b4dd70: got connection request from 192.168.100.1:38106 on a device tmfifo_net0 which was not present during UCP initialization
[07:32:45:690690][DOCA][ERR][ALLREDUCE::UCX:729]: Failed to create UCP endpoint: Destination is unreachable
Somebody can help me?
The DOCA allreuce application example can run correctly.
